# Remove punctuation from list using for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7.13 and I'm stuck on an assignment. I'm completely new to python.

I'm supposed to remove punctuation from names in a list, this is the code that has been given to me:

```
import string
name = ""
result = []
persons = [["Lisa", "Georgia"],
           ["Chris", "New York"],
           ["Wes", "Oregon"],
           ["Jo-Ann", "Texas"],
           ["Angie", "Florida"]]
```

I want to print the exact same list, except "Jo-Ann" needs to be printed as "JoAnn". The assignment says that I need to check every character and if it's not a punctuation I need to add it to the variable "name". I'm completely lost; I have no idea how to do this with a for loop. 
My teacher gave me some pointers:

```
for every letter in name
if letter is not a punctuation, add to variable "name"
print
```

This doesn't make things clearer for a complete newbie like me. Is there someone that can give me some pointers? I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: What was your approach?

Comment: You need two for loops. the first one to go through every person in `persons` and the second to go through every letter of that person's name.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The way things typically work here is that you provide the code you've written to attempt your problem, explain what it's doing vs. what it *should* be doing, and then we can show you why your code is acting the way it is, and suggest how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to WeDoYourHomework.com ... :P  ["Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import string
new_persons = [[x[0].translate(None, string.punctuation), x[1]] for x in persons]
```

Explanation:

1. to remove punctuations from a string, we can use `'one-example'.translate(None, string.punctuation)`
2. `[... for x in persons]` is a list comprehension (short-hand looping)  to create a new list by using elements( assigned to `x` on every loop) in the list `persons`
3. Within a loop iteration, `x` is just the inner array of two elements. e.g. `["Jo-Ann", "Texas"]`
4. `x[0]` is "Jon-Ann" and `x[1]` is "Texas"
5. `[x[0].translate(None, string.punctuation), x[1]]` means we create an array of two elements from `x` but with the punctuations removed from the first one.

Comment: While this may be correct, I'm not sure this is helpful for a complete python newbie to understand things better ...

Answer (score 1):

I think this a pretty obvious and simple way how a beginner could do it.

```
import string

result = []
# Loop over the [name, state] pairs.
for [name, state] in persons:
    # Make a new name by only keeping desired
    # characters.
    newName = ""
    for letter in name:
        if letter not in string.punctuation:
            newName += letter
    # Add to result.
    result.append([newName, state])
```

It makes use of a few very handy Python tricks to know!

- The first one is *unpacking* of composed values in a loop, in this case the `[name, state]` pairs. It roughly amounts to doing like

  ```
  [a, b] = [1, 2]
  ```

  to extract values from a list.
- The second is implicit looping over characters in a string. If you write

  ```
  for l in "word":
      print(l)
  ```

  you'll see that each letter is printed on a new line. Python automatically splits a string in characters.

Afterwards, you can start looking into [list comprehensions](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php).

Answer (score 0):

get all punctuation marks in a string
use triple quotes for marking start and end of string

```
import string
punc_marks=string.punctuation
name = ''
for i in persons:
    for j in i:
        for k in j:
            if k not in punc_marks:
                name+=k
print(name+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using your teacher's approach, basically what you should learn right now and what your teacher wants:

```
import string
name = ""
result = []
persons = [["Lisa", "Georgia"],
           ["Chris", "New York"],
           ["Wes", "Oregon"],
           ["Jo-Ann", "Texas"],
           ["Angie", "Florida"]]
for person in persons:
    for every_letter in person[0]: # name
        if every_letter not in string.punctuation: # check if it isn't a punctuation
            name += every_letter # add it to name
    result.append([name, person[1]]) # add the name with no punctuation to result
    name = "" # reset name
print(result)
```

Please try to learn from this and not just copy and paste to your home work

Answer (score 0):

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')   
tokenizer=tokenizer.tokenize(persons)
```